# How to return value as an observable in angular 6

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I want to return value (any data) from service to component as an observable. After a couple of digging into observables found following solution:

```
class AppService {
    getData(value) {
        // do we have any other best way to return value as an observable
        return Observer.create((observer) => {
            observer.next(value);
        });
    }
}

class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
        this.dataService$ = this.appService.getData().subscribe((data) => {
            // do some task with data
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: `return of(value)`

Comment: You already found the answer, what's the question here ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just return like below

```
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';

...

getData(value) : Observable<any> {
   // Simple way of sending value using of operator.
   return Observable.of(value);
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: thanks it worked, do you know if I need to do either way means returning observable as a value;

Comment: yes you need to return observable as value so that you can subscribe to obsevable to get data in component

Answer (score 7):

Use `of` like so:

```
import { of } from 'rxjs';
...
return of(value);
```

which is equivalent to:

```
return new Observable(obs => obs.next(value));
```

However, if you want to convert a given value (e.g. a Promise, an Observable-like, an Array, an iterable or an array-like object) you may want to use `from`:

```
import { from } from 'rxjs';
...
return from(value);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I do

In your service file :

First I declare my observable this way

```
  myObs: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
```

In a method you can set your datas into your obs :

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4,5];
this.myObs.next(myArray);
```

If you want your "controller" to subscribe this obs, in your service, just expose a getter :

```
public getMyObs(){
return this.myObs.asObservable()
}
```

And in your "controller" you can call it this way :

```
 ngOnInit() {

this.myService.getMyObs().subscribe(datas => {
    Do What you want with your datas
  }
}
```