# How to return observable mock value in Angular

Tags: angular, observable

I am using below code calling API which is working fine. Now I don't want to call API instead just return a true value. When I return true throwing error

```
export interface EmployeeStatus{
  hasActive: boolean;
}


 public getStatus(Id: number): Observable<EmployeeStatus> {
     return true;
      //return this.http.get<EmployeeStatus>(`APIurl`);
  }
```

Comment: `return of(true)` - https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/of

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return value as an observable in angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54999187/how-to-return-value-as-an-observable-in-angular-6)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39032365/11013049

Comment: @ZuhairNaqi an empty observable is something different - that would complete without emitting.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved as below for custom modal.

```
public getStatus(Id: number): Observable<EmployeeStatus> {
     const employeeStatus={hasActive:true}
      return of(employeeStatus)
  }
```